# Having issues with the upsert operation using javascript button

Tags: javascript, community

Hi  I have tried to create an  upsert operation using the javascript button. I am having difficulty in making it happen. The code is shown below.

So, the basic idea would be when a user clicks the " Send with CudaSign" button it would automatically create a task. This task however checks if there was a Task created before with "Invoice Issued" as the status then it would overwrite it. If not it will create a new record.

The code for overwriting works well. However,if it has to create a new record I get an error:

> "Id not defined "

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var q =  new sforce.SObject("Task");

var q1 = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, WhatId, Subject from Task Where WhatId = '{!Product_and_Services__c.Id}' AND Subject = 'Invoice Issued'  ");

var records = q1.getArray("records");
q.Id =  records[0].Id;

if( records[0].Id == null)
{
q.WhatId = "{!Product_and_Services__c.Id}";
q.Subject = "Invoice Issued";
q.Department__c = "Sales"; 
q.Sales_Notes__c = "Order ID:{!Product_and_Services__c.Name}, Invoice send to {!Product_and_Services__c.Contact_name__c} ";
q.status = "Completed";

/*q.Account_Rating__c = "{!ABS(Product_and_Services__c.Total_Discounted_Price_del__c)}"; */

q.Current_Sales_Status__c = "Active Invoiced";
q.ActivityDate = "{!SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(TODAY()), "/", "-")}";

result = sforce.connection.create([q]);

} 
else{
q.Id = "{!Task.Id}";

q.WhatId = "{!Product_and_Services__c.Id}";
q.Subject = "Invoice Issued";
q.Department__c = "Sales"; 
q.Sales_Notes__c = "Order ID:{!Product_and_Services__c.Name}, Invoice send to {!Product_and_Services__c.Contact_name__c} ";
q.status = "Completed";

/*q.Account_Rating__c = "{!ABS(Product_and_Services__c.Total_Discounted_Price_del__c)}"; */

q.Current_Sales_Status__c = "Active Invoiced";
q.ActivityDate = "{!SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(TODAY()), "/", "-")}";


result = sforce.connection.upsert("Id",[q],false);

}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. You have not asked a question. The more detail you add to your post, the better the community can help you. Please **[edit]** your post to actually ask a question, and include any error messages you have already received, whether they are compile errors or run-time errors.

Comment: you're assigning id to the record q.Id = and trying to insert it. it might be an issue

Comment: yes so I used the if else loop  if( records[0].Id == null) { } I get the same error.

Comment: Did you forget to update the code, I still see the line q.Id =  records[0].Id; in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom button you're trying to query Tasks for custom object.
If records exist, you want to update task, otherwise create new one.

But in case when query result is empty, you attempting to assign id from non existing record to your variable:

```
q.Id =  records[0].Id;
```

that's throwing an exception.

You should change:

```
q.Id =  records[0].Id;

if( records[0].Id == null)
{
```

To:

```
//q.Id =  records[0].Id;

if( records.length == 0) {
//create new task here
    result = sforce.connection.create([q]);
} else {
    q.Id =  records[0].Id;
    //q.Id = "{!Task.Id}";
    //clone/update records[0] here
    result = sforce.connection.upsert("Id",[q],false);
}
```